# Is there a way to conditionally render certain components from _app.js file based on user login?

Tags: material-ui, next-auth, next.js13

I am working on nextjs project with MUI. I want to render some of the components used in _app.js file only if user is not logged in. Following is the code snippet from _app.js file.

```
export default function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps } = props;
  // const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  // console.log("session", session)
  const sessionThroughGet = getSession().then(res => console.log("Printing response", res));
  console.log("getSession", sessionThroughGet);
 
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
          <CssBaseline />
          <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
            <Header />
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
              <Box component="main">
                <Component {...pageProps} />
              </Box>
            </LocalizationProvider>
            <Footer />
          </SessionProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </CacheProvider>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} position="bottom-right" />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  emotionCache: PropTypes.object,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

I tried to use useSession() and getSession() hooks for conditionally rendering the  and  components but through useSession() i am getting

```
Error: [next-auth]: `useSession` must be wrapped in a <SessionProvider />
```

whereas getSession() hook is returning promise and value undefined and i was expecting it to return null.